# 7-zip files on Linux with AES-256 encryption

Tags: windows-7, linux, 7-zip

I have a requirement to zip up some files in Linux with 7zip using AES-256 encryption.  The end user will be opening in Windows with 7zip.  I'm using the following command:

```
7za a myfile.zip test.txt -tzip -mem=AES256 -mx9
```

The problem is that when I open the zip archive in Windows, the Method shows "Deflate" and does not say anything about AES-256.

[image: 7zip windows screenshot]

**How can I (and more importantly the end user) be sure that its using AES-256 as the encryption method?**

[Here is the doc](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method.htm) on how to set the encryption method, which I believe I've set correctly.

Linux 7za version:

```
me@myhost~> 7za -version

7-Zip (A) [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)
```

The Linux host is SLES 11 SP2, and for Windows I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: Did you mean to use a password?

Comment: ah!  yes I did mean to use a password.  I've been testing, testing, testing, and mistakenly left that option out.  Adding back in `-pmypassword` to the command did the trick and I can see `AE-256 Deflate` when opened in Windows.  Can you post as an answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

7-Zip will refuse to encrypt the data unless you provide a password, since it won't know what key you want to encrypt it with:

```
7za a myfile.zip test.txt -tzip -mem=AES256 -mx9 -pmypassword
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had to add `-pmypassword` to the command.

Comment: If you want to encrypt filenames as well, see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/928275/7z-command-line-with-highest-encryption-aes-256-encrypting-the-filenames

Comment: Somebody who has time please submit a feature request to 7za to refuse creating an archive or at least print a clear warning message when command line options are used to change the encryption settings but no encryption is requested via the "-p" option.

Answer (score 8):

> How can I (and more importantly the end user) be sure that its using AES-256 as the encryption method?

You can use `7z l -slt myfile.zip`, it should output `AES-256` (amongst other things).

If you choose the 7z format (e.g., with `7za a -t7z myfile.7z test.txt -tzip -mem=AES256 -mx9 -pmypassword`), `7z l -slt myfile.7z` should output `7zAES:19` (which is the same as `AES-256`).

https://sourceforge.net/p/p7zip/patches/25/#3da5 :

> Igor Pavlov: `7zAES:19` means AES-256 + (2^19) SHA-256 iterations in password to key function.